# Sql Query for Total Salary Deptno wise where more than two employess exits from the below table (tried lot can any one help me with this)

Tags: sql

Empid     Deptno   Sal
1           1       1000
1           2       2000
2           3       3000
3           4       4000
4           1       5000
2           2       6000

Comment: Clear you question. These are three columns or three tables

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :

```
select Sum(Sal),DeptNo from Table1 
where Deptno in (
select Deptno from Table1
group by Deptno
having Count(DeptNo)>1
) group by DeptNo
```